# c++ array copy, address issues

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-arrays

i've got some memory issues when iterating an array. Here is my code :

```
...
std::vector<uint32_t> iD(32);
packBytes(intialPad.data(), intialPad.size(), iD);
const char32_t*  modifiedInitPad = iD.data();
uint32_t H[8] = { 0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19 };
...

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{

        uint32_t block[16];
        std::copy(modifiedInitPad + (i * 16), modifiedInitPad + (i * 16 ) + 16, block);


        uint32_t w[64];

        uint32_t temp[10];

        transformBlock(block, w, temp, H);

}

...

void transformBlock(uint32_t* block, uint32_t* W, uint32_t* temp, uint32_t* H) { 
   const uint32_t K[] = {
    0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
    0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
    0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
    0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
    0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
    0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
    0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
    0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
    0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
    0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
    0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
    0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
    0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
    0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
    0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
    0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

const uint32_t size = 16;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    W[i] = block[i];
}
for (int t = 16; t < 64; ++t)
    W[t] = crypto::f6(W[t - 2]) + W[t - 7] + crypto::f5(W[t - 15]) + W[t - 16];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    temp[i] = H[i];
}


for (int t = 0; t < 64; ++t) {
    temp[8] = temp[7] + crypto::f4(temp[4]) + crypto::f1(temp[4], temp[5],  temp[6]) + K[t] + W[t];
    temp[9] = crypto::f3(temp[0]) + crypto::f2(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
    temp[7] = temp[6];
    temp[6] = temp[5];
    temp[5] = temp[4];
    temp[4] = temp[3] + temp[8];
    temp[3] = temp[2];
    temp[2] = temp[1];
    temp[1] = temp[0];
    temp[0] = temp[8] + temp[9];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    H[i] = crypto::add(H[i], temp[i]);
}
}
...
namespace crypto {
namespace {
    uint32_t word(int a, int b, int c, int d)  {
        a &= 0xff;
        b &= 0xff;
        c &= 0xff;
        d &= 0xff;
        int val = a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
        return val;
    }

    uint32_t ROTR(uint32_t number, unsigned bits)   {
        return (number >> bits) | (number << (32 - bits));
    }

    uint32_t f1(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)  {
        return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);
    }
    uint32_t f2(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z)   {
        return (x & y) ^ (x&z) ^ (y&z);
    }
    uint32_t f3(uint32_t x)  {
        return ROTR(x, 2) ^ ROTR(x, 13) ^ ROTR(x, 22);
    }
    uint32_t f4(uint32_t x)  {
        return ROTR(x, 6) ^ ROTR(x, 11) ^ ROTR(x, 25);
    }
    uint32_t f5(uint32_t x)  {
        return ROTR(x, 7) ^ ROTR(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3);
    }
    uint32_t f6(uint32_t x)  {
        return ROTR(x, 17) ^ ROTR(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10);
    }

    uint32_t add(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
}
```

when i = 0, everything goes well. But when i = 1, modifiedInitPad does not have the same address as previously. So i get an exception at "std:copy(..)".

Any idea ?

Comment: When `i` is `1`, you don't copy anything. When `i` is `2`, you run into trouble because 32 is larger than 16.

Comment: `std::copy(x+32,x+16,...)` needs fixing, as juan said

Comment: My bad, wrong copy/paste. i have edited content. If i put a breakpoint after "transformBlock(block, w, temp, H);" address of modifiedInitPad is changed.

Comment: We'd have to see your source code for transformBlock. If H is declared on the stack further up it's possible you're writing beyond its bounds (all the way into modifiedInitPad's memory).

Comment: I've edited content with a bit more code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the loop below you may have a buffer overrun

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     H[i] = crypto::add(H[i], temp[i]);
```

size is 16 and as H should be an 8 element array using H[i] here lead to an overrun for I = 8 and 9

Comment: As i said previously, it was a wrong copy/paste. the problem is after "transformBlock". Address of modifiedInitPad is modified.